# Was the Flare-Flare Fruit that Sabo ate real? Or was it a fake made by Caesar?

Tags: one-piece

How did Doffy get that Flare-Flare Fruit? Because until now I am still confused how the Devil Fruits spread around the world. Everything about the Devil Fruits is still unclear, like:

1. Do they grow in the same tree or each of them has their own tree (Flare-Flare Tree maybe)?
2. After the users died, will the fruit grow in the same tree or just fall to random places like Dragon Balls?

Comment: Well, previous owner of fruit was dead for 2 years, so it is really possible, that fruit was regrown, and taken into certain place in the world. But, without knowing actual source of devil fruits, it is hard to tell.

Comment: We do know that when the user dies, the fruit reincarnates, almost instantly in at least one case (Smiley). It could be the nearest fruit, or it could be some random fruit in the area, or much of anything. All we know is some fruit somewhere becomes the Flare Flare Fruit eventually, and Doflamingo runs a Black Market, so getting his hands on it is unlikely, but very possible.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your 1st question

> How did Doffy get that Flare-Flare Fruit?

just like Kaz Rodgers said

> Doflamingo was a black market dealer so naturally his connections probably ended up finding it.

2nd, three of your questions together:

> 1. until now I am still confused how the Devil Fruits spread around the world
> 2. Do they grow in the same tree or each of them has their own tree (Flare-Flare Tree maybe)?
> 3. After the users died, will the fruit grow in the same tree or just fall to random places like Dragon Balls?

For starters, 2. and 3. we don't know much about Devil Fruits either, besides what we have told so far and seen. For example:

1. When a Devil Fruit user dies, their ability is reborn into another Fruit of the same kind. Instead of growing from a plant, the ability simply regenerates inside another existing Fruit

*Spoiler*

> As seen when Smiley "died" and the Sara Sara no Mi, Model: Axolotl transplanted itself into a nearby apple.

**BUT** Oda has pointed out in [SBS Volume 48](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/SBS_Volume_48)

"For more detail, you'll just have to wait for a certain professor to make his appearance in the story, and explain exactly what the Devil Fruits REALLY are... eventually."

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is the real flare-flare fruit. The logic behind it is because Blackbeard and his men desperately wanted to have the power of the flare-flare fruit along with the power of the earth-quake fruit and the other dfs that they have been working so hard to amass.

Doflamingo was a black market dealer so naturally his connections probably ended up finding it.

When the user of a fruit dies the fruit reincarnates somewhere else in the world for someone else to go for how that is determined specifically is unknown at least for now.